# Microsoft botframework failed: [400] Bad Request on Facebook Messenger

Tags: node.js, facebook, botframework

So I'm getting a `[400] Bad Request` on messenges on my Facebook Messenger bot.

I haven't previously been getting this. Error:

```
Error: Request to 'https://facebook.botframework.com/v3/conversations/some-randomID/activities/anotherID' failed: [400] Bad Request
```

I've had a search around and from the Github issues I've come to think it was something related to the state storage. From this thread here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2272

I've read through the nodejs sdk docs and added in:

```
bot.set('persistConversationData', false);
bot.set('persistUserData', false);
```

And I've even console logged out the below in one of my intents

```
console.log(session.conversationData, '<<');
console.log(session.privateConversationData, '<<');
console.log(session.dialogData, '<<');
console.log(session.userData, '<<');
```

and I get back

```
[0] {} '<<'
[0] {} '<<'
[0] { 'BotBuilder.Data.WaterfallStep': 0 } '<<'
[0] {} '<<'
```

Has anyone come across this issue. Know what's going on?

---

### UPDATE

I've been testing it through the emulator and it all seems to be working fine through there. I don't get the error.

I know, closing the emulator kills all the persistent storage so I'm feeling that it's related to that issue but unsure why my currently `bot.set` method isn't working.

---

### My `server.js` config

```
import request from 'request';
import botDefault from './bot';

const restify = require('restify');
const builder = require('botbuilder');

const server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});

const connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
  appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
  appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD,
});
const bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
bot.set('persistConversationData', false);
bot.set('persistUserData', false);

server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

bot.beginDialogAction('Help', 'Help', { matches: /^help/i });
bot.beginDialogAction('/', '/', { matches: /^get started|Get Started/i });

botDefault(bot, builder);
```

Comment: What version of the sdk is the bot using?

Comment: @EricDahlvang i'm using botbuilder `v3.8.4` and restify `v4.3.0`

Comment: are you using a custom state client?  Please refer to: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/21/Saving-State-Azure-Nodejs/

Comment: @EricDahlvang I'll have a read through that thank you. I've not really set up any custom state client. Literally just using the out the box tutorial setup using `botbuilder` and `restify` with obviously my own dialogs and that

Comment: You could debug your bot locally using ngrok and visual studio code.  This might help you determine what the problem is.  Here's a post that explains how to configure ngrok for a bot: https://www.robinosborne.co.uk/2016/09/19/debugging-botframework-locally-using-ngrok/

Comment: Another thing to try is sending a ' /deleteProfile' message (without the single quotes, and note the space before the slash).  This should be interpreted by the bot, and you should see a response as: 'User profile deleted!'

Comment: @EricDahlvang as in create a new dialog that catches `/deleteProfile`?

Comment: No, just send ' /deleteProfile' to the bot in facebook messenger (without the quote and include the leading space).

Comment: @EricDahlvang I read that `/deleteProfile` is built in. But when I send it, it just triggers the next dialog. Like it's moving down the stack. Something for me to debug I think.